# Event Page - ATTENDING OR NOT ATTENDING - How would I implement this?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to add these two buttons to the events pages of my website.

Basically, just like any other event page you might come across online, for example Facebook,
you get the option to say whether you are attending or not attending the event.

And there is a section on the page with a number of people attending etc.

I would like to know the best solution to tackle this.

I'm not asking you to code it for me, just to point me in the right direction. 
I was thinking of something like, if the user clicks attending, their username or id is put into the database where the event exists and is added to an attending field in some kind of array format. Same for if they choose to not attend but in a notAttending field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're half way there, at least having the concept of a `user` and `event` entities - the only step of the puzzle that you're missing is the concept of an `attendance` entity that stores if the user has declined/is required/is attending/failed to turn up/etc. - so each `user` has an `attendance` for each `event` they're invited to; in database terms this is a many to many relationship (a user can be invited to many events, and an event can be attended by many users), so would typically live in a dedicated table.

Comment: Good explanation thinking of entities than speaking of database tables!

Answer (score 1):

I would create a table called `rsvps` or `event_responses` something to that effect.

It would have three columns:

- user_id - pk value of the user.
- event_id - pk value of the event.
- attending - boolean.

`attending` should be `NOT NULL`.  That way the only data in the table is generated in two situations:

1. User indicates they will attend event.
2. User indicates they will not attend event.

If a user has not responded, they will not be in the table for that event.  That you way you can easily get a count for "Attending", "Not Attending" and "Yet to Respond".

**UI**

Using jQuery, add two buttons to the event page: "Attending" and "Not Attending".  Bind a click event to each and fire off an AJAX request when clicked.  That way the interface is responsive.

Comment: @BenToms Absolutely!  Does that get you pointed in the right direction, or is there another piece you want to talk out?

Comment: I think I should be ok! With all three answers on here I think I get it now so I'll give it ago. Thanks again.

Comment: may I just ask...will this create a new row for each person who is attending? Although I can work with that, I get the feeling on a large scale, (hundreds of events with hundreds of users) I could reach the maximum amount of data on the disk very quickly. Maybe I'm misunderstanding it? Thanks.

Comment: @BenToms I don't think that you would have an issue with hundreds of events and hundreds of users.  I think you may have issues with millions of events and users, but, MySQL will certainly handle hundreds of users at hundreds of events.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea sounds good. You could have a table named `event_attendants` having the columns `event_id`, `user_id` and `status` (don't forget the primary key). That's it. `status` could be a ternary property so you can have a facebook-like status *yes*, *no* and *not sure* or similar.

You can even do the button functionality with AJAX so it's a pretty quick UI.